# Can I merge the ADF_Publish branch to a different branch?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

We are designing a branching strategy for an data application which uses ADF and Data Brick .

Question is if one can merge the ADF_publish branch to the release branch and then from the release branch run the deployment . Is it possible or we must use default created ADF_Publish branch .

Comment: May I know why you want to use another branch instead of the adf_publish branch? AFAIK, triggers and linked service may not work as expected as they use the published version on the adf_publish / published branch

Comment: Actually we are trying to build a CI/CD of ADF and Databrick application together- we were thinking keeping the code for notebook and ADF ina single branch will help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADF_Publish branch will generate ARM templates for deployment automatically. Those templates you will be selecting as part of your release pipeline to perform deployment.

So, after merging ARM templates from ADF_Publish branch to another branch, if you are using same ARM template files from another branch to release deployment then it should work.